# C Unexpected segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement the avl tree in C. The following is part of my code. struct Node contains structure variables including an integer key, height and 3 points to the parent, left and right child of that node.

In the following code, I am inserting "8" into a tree with "2,6". I printed out the key of the right child of the node (i.e. 6). However, when I passed the pointer to the insertright() function and printed the right child right away, it is not 6 but a mysterious number. As I need to go to the right child of "6", it gives me a segmentation fault on the next step.

The weirdest thing is that I compile and run this using gcc on my Macbook. But when I run on some online compiler (i.e. repl.it), it works well for this case (and segmentation fault still exists when more elements are added).

Thanks!

```
//*tree is the root node of the tree
void insert(struct Node *tree, int element)
{
    printf("tree rightchild node: %d, element: %d\n", tree->rightchild->key, element);
    (element < (tree->key))? insertleft(tree, element): insertright(tree, element);
}

int insertright(struct Node *self, int element){
printf("right insertion\n");
printf("rightchild node: %d\n", self->rightchild->key);

if (self->rightchild != &emptynode)
{
    //printf("self node: %d\n", self->rightchild->key);
    insert(self->rightchild, element);
}

// Output
tree rightchild node: 6, element: 8
right insertion
rightchild node: 1372646176
```

The orignal code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int key, height;
    struct Node *parent, *leftchild, *rightchild;
};

struct Node emptynode = {.key = 0, .height = 0, .parent = NULL, .leftchild = NULL, .rightchild = NULL};

int max(int a, int b);
void insert(struct Node *node, int element);
int insertleft(struct Node *self, int element);
int insertright(struct Node *self, int element);
void rotate(struct Node *self, int flag);
void leftRotation(struct Node *self);
void rightRotation(struct Node *self);
int query(struct Node *self, int value);

int main()
{
    // int test[] = {2,6,8,4,10,20,12,14,16,18,30,40,50,22,24,28,26,48,46,44,42,34,32,36,38,100,60,70,80,88,76,62};
    int test[] = {2,6,8};
    int n = sizeof(test)/sizeof(int);
    struct Node root = {.key = test[0], .height = 1, .parent = &emptynode, .leftchild = &emptynode, .rightchild = &emptynode};
    struct Node *tree = &root;

    for(int i = 1; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
        printf("elment inserted: %d\n", test[i]);
        printf("before insertion: %d\n", tree->rightchild->key);
        insert(tree, test[i]);
        if (tree->parent != &emptynode)
            tree = tree->parent;
        printf("root key: %d\n", tree->key);
    }

    return 0;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a>b)? a: b;
}

void insert(struct Node *tree, int element)
{
    printf("tree rightchild node: %d, element: %d\n", tree->rightchild->key, element);
    //printf("self node: %d\n", tree->rightchild->key);
    (element < (tree->key))? insertleft(tree, element): insertright(tree, element);
}

int insertleft(struct Node *self, int element)
{
    printf("left insertion\n");
    if (self->leftchild != &emptynode)
    {
        insert(self->leftchild, element);
    }
    else 
    {
        struct Node left = {.key = element, .height = 1, .parent = self, .leftchild = &emptynode, .rightchild = &emptynode};
        self->leftchild = &left;
        self->height = 2;
        struct Node *node = self;
        while(node->parent != &emptynode)
        {
            node = node->parent;
            int rotationflag = self->leftchild->height - self->rightchild->height;
            if (abs(rotationflag) > 1)
            {
                rotate(node, rotationflag);
                return 0;
            } 
            else
            {
                node->height = 1+max(node->leftchild->height, node->rightchild->height);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int insertright(struct Node *self, int element)
{
    printf("right insertion\n");
    printf("rightchild node: %d\n", self->rightchild->key);

    if (self->rightchild != &emptynode)
    {
        //printf("self node: %d\n", self->rightchild->key);
        insert(self->rightchild, element);
    } 
    else
    {
        struct Node right = {.key = element, .height = 1, .parent = self, .leftchild = &emptynode, .rightchild = &emptynode};
        self->rightchild = &right;
        self->height = 2;
        struct Node *node = self;
        while(node->parent != &emptynode)
        {
            node = node->parent;
            int rotationflag = node->leftchild->height - node->rightchild->height;
            if (abs(rotationflag) > 1)
            {
                rotate(node, rotationflag);
                return 0;
            } 
            else
            {
                node->height = 1+max(node->leftchild->height, node->rightchild->height);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void rotate(struct Node *self, int flag)
{
    if (flag > 0)
    {
        if (self->leftchild->leftchild->height == self->height -1)
            leftRotation(self);
        else
        {
            rightRotation(self->leftchild);
            leftRotation(self);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        if (self->rightchild->rightchild->height == self->height -1)
            rightRotation(self);
        else
        {
            leftRotation(self->rightchild);
            rightRotation(self);
        }
    }
}

void leftRotation(struct Node *self)
{
    printf("left rotation\n");
    struct Node *u = self->parent;
    struct Node *a = self;
    struct Node *b = self->leftchild;
    struct Node *B = b->rightchild;
    a->parent = b;
    b->rightchild = a;
    a->leftchild = B;
    B->parent = a;
    b->parent = u;

    if (u->rightchild == a)
        u->rightchild = b;
    else
        u->leftchild = b;

    b->height = a->height;
    a->height--;
}

void rightRotation(struct Node *self)
{
    printf("right rotation\n");
    struct Node *u = self->parent;
    struct Node *a = self;
    struct Node *b = self->rightchild;
    struct Node *B = b->leftchild;
    a->parent = b;
    b->leftchild = a;
    a->rightchild = B;
    B->parent = a;
    b->parent = u;

    if (u->rightchild == a)
        u->rightchild = b;
    else
        u->leftchild = b;

    b->height = a->height;
    a->height--;
}

int query(struct Node *self, int value)
{
    static int result;
    if (self == &emptynode)
        return result;
    if (self->key == value)
        return value;
    else if (self->key > value)
        return query(self->leftchild, value);
    else
    {
        result = self->key;
        return query(self->rightchild, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration for `emptynode` ?

Comment: It seems you need to read about dynamic memory allocation in C. In the linked code you are storing the address of a local variable into the tree. However the memory of local variables becomes invalid after the function returns leading to the mysterious numbers and segmentation faults.

Comment: _The weirdest thing is that I compile and run this using gcc on my Macbook. But when I run on some online compiler (i.e. repl.it), it works well for this case (and segmentation fault still exists when more elements are added)._ There is no better illustration of undefined behavior than what you have described here. Anyway, you haven't posted enough code to reveal the problem. Asking users to go offsite to your repo isn't generally well-received. Your chances of receiving help are greatly improved if you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, that's 
struct Node{
  int key, height;
  struct Node *parent, *leftchild, *rightchild;
};

struct Node emptynode = {.key = 0, .height = 0, .parent = NULL, .leftchild = NULL, .rightchild = NULL};

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, instead of hiding it in a comment. Maybe consider separating the output from the code.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the way you used the ternary operator. It is meant for expressions, but the way you use it relies on when evaluation happens, instead of making a meaningful value. Use an "if" construct instead of `(element < (tree->key))? insertleft(tree, element): insertright(tree, element);`. What and where is returned from `insertright()`?

Comment: @pokfung you have revealed the type, but not the declaration. Can you show where it was declared? In the global scope, inside a function etc.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I have just added the original code to the question. @Yunnosch, let me try to use "if". And inside insertright(), the operation of pointers will be done there so no return value is needed. I make it an int function just because for insertion, there is at most one rotation, so after a rotation is done, I terminate the function by the return.

 I tried to use "if" but the problem still exists. :(

Comment: `insert` calls `insertleft` or `insertright`, and `insertleft` or `insertright` calls `insert` and then `insert` calls `insertleft` or `insertright`, and so on. Bad design at first place.